# Can't get 2 different Regex finditer calls to work inside a loop in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

My code is looping through files in a folder looking for lines of text followed by either "Hot Task" or "Short Suspense".  I want to collect those lines into a dict keyed with the filename.

I tried:

```
for file in os.listdir(path_code):
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
if filename.endswith(".docx"):
    target = os.path.join(path_str,filename)
    text = docx2txt.process(target)
    hotiter = re.finditer('(.*)(?<!BLACK= )(Hot Task.*)',text)
    shortiter = re.finditer('(.*)(?<!PURPLE = )(Short Suspense.*)',text)
    hottext = [text[match.start():match.end()] for match in hotiter]
    shorttext = [text[match.start():match.end()] for match in shortiter]
    if not hottext:
        continue
    else:
        hotdict[filename] = hottext
        continue
    if not shorttext:
        continue
    else:
        shortdict[filename] = shorttext
        continue        

    continue
else:
    continue
```

This yields the expected results for the 'Hot Task' search, but I get no results for 'Short Suspense,' but if I comment out the 'Hot Task' search, the 'Short Suspense' returns the expected results.

I can't figure out why they don't both work.  I think I could do this with a second for loop, but I don't want to have to go through all my files twice.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 1. Please make sure your code is formatted properly. Python is extremely sensitive to formatting. 2. Research the purpose of the Python **continue** statement.

Comment: Thanks!  The formatting was correct, I did a bad job pasting it here.  Removing the extra continue statements solved the problem.